# What happened to the .pull-left and .pull-right classes in Bootstrap 4?

Tags: bootstrap-4

In the newest version the pull-left and pull-right have been replaced by .pull-{xs,sm,md,lg,xl}-{left,right,none}

That means that instead of writing a simple `class="pull-right"`, I will have now to write `class="pull-md-right pull-xl-right pull-lg-right pull-sm-right pull-xs-right"`

Is there a less tedious way to do it?

Comment: It looks like you've not quite understood the mobile first approach. `.pull-xs-right` would cause the object to float right on all screen sizes, since the css cascades upwards to the larger devices too. P.s. Maybe it has changed in the more recent versions but you should be using `.float-right` rather than `.pull-right`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Back in 2016 when this question was originally asked, the answer was:

```
$('.pull-right').addClass('pull-xs-right').removeClass('pull-right')
```

But now the accepted answer should be Robert Went's.

Comment: `.float-{sm,md,lg,xl}-{left,right,none}` now floats left/right/none whereas `.pull-left` and `.pull-right` have been removed.

Comment: pull-right is back, but if that would have been the case just use css ```.pull-right{@extend .pull-xs-right;}```

Comment: This was answered 9/2016. The correct answer is now Robert Went's.

Comment: It seems rough you get 21 down votes for an answer that's just deprecated?

Comment: @PhillipSenn consider updating your answer so you aren't losing points for being a team player.

Comment: Well I mainly used push/pull on my grid... I found that in bootstrap 4, the new implementation was order... Since it is using flexbox afterall...

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#order-classes

Answer (score 243):

### Bootstrap 4

The classes are `float-right` `float-sm-right` etc.

The media queries are mobile-first, so using `float-sm-right` would affect small screen sizes and anything wider, so there's no reason to add a class for each width. Just use the smallest screen you want to affect or `float-right` for all screen widths.

Official Docs:

Classes: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/utilities/float/

Updating: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/migration/#utilities

If you are updating an existing project based on an earlier version of Bootstrap, you can use sass extend to apply the rules to the old class names:

```
.pull-right {
    @extend .float-right;
}
.pull-left {
    @extend .float-left;
}
```

### Bootstrap 5

With Bootstrap 5, float classes still exist, but `-left` and `-right` are replaced with `-start` and `-end`.

Responsive versions are still available such as `.float-md-start`, `.float-lg-none`.

Official Bootstrap 5 float docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/utilities/float/

Comment: documentation about this: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/#utilities and https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/float/

Answer (score 56):

**Update 2021 (as of Bootstrap 5)**

Because of new RTL support, `float-left` and `float-right` have been replaced with `float-start` and `float-end` in Bootstrap 5.

**Update 2018 (as of Bootstrap 4.3)**

Yes, `pull-left` and `pull-right` have been replaced with `float-left` and `float-right` in Bootstrap 4.

However, *floats* will not work in all cases since Bootstrap 4 is now **flexbox**.

To align flexbox children to the right, use auto-margins (ie: `ml-auto`) or the flexbox utils (ie: `justify-content-end`, `align-self-end`, etc..).

### Examples

**Navs:**

```
<ul class="nav">
   <li><a href class="nav-link">Link</a></li>
   <li><a href class="nav-link">Link</a></li>
   <li class="ml-auto"><a href class="nav-link">Right</a></li>
</ul>
```

**Breadcrumbs:**

```
<ul class="breadcrumb">
    <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="/">Link</a></li>
    <li class="ml-auto"><a href="/">Right</a></li>
</ul>

https://www.codeply.com/go/6ITgrV7pvL
```

**Grid:**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-3">Left</div>
    <div class="col-3 ml-auto">Right</div>
</div>
```

Comment: ml-auto is exactly what I needed in my navbar

Comment: float-end works perfect in my situation

Answer (score 18):

Changed to `float-right` `float-left` `float-xx-left` and `float-xx-right`

Comment: Swear to god, Bootstrap make everyones lives harder by doing this. They brick any backwards compability by changing class names. 
1) Is it that hard to not delete your old class names, and 2) Why would they introduce a new class name for the same component, forcing mass html updates, when instead they could update a few lines of CSS, keep the original classes the same, and then implement additional classes to run in tandem with the existing ones?

Why Bootstrap, why...?

Answer (score 7):

If you want to use those with columns in another work with `col-*` classes, you can use `order-*` classes.

You can control the order of your columns with order classes. see more in [Bootstrap 4 documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#order-classes)

A simple from bootstrap docs:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      First, but unordered
    </div>
    <div class="col order-12">
      Second, but last
    </div>
    <div class="col order-1">
      Third, but first
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This worked. For some reason `pull-right` and `pull-left` don't work on grid columns in `4.1`

Comment: That's right. The order is the way you would recreate the push/pull on rows since the rows now use flexbox.

Answer (score 7):

**Update 2021, Bootstrap 5**

In *bootstrap 5* these classes have been renamed to `.float-end` and `.float-start`.

Docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/float/

**Example:**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
       <button class="btn btn-primary float-end">Login</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

Thay are removed.

Use `float-left` instead of `pull-left`. 
And `float-right` instead of `pull-right`.

Check bootstrap Documentation [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/float/):

> Added .float-{sm,md,lg,xl}-{left,right,none} classes for responsive
>   floats and removed .pull-left and .pull-right since they’re redundant
>   to .float-left and .float-right.

Answer (score 5):

Nothing else was working for me. This one did. This might help someone.

```
<div class="clearfix">
  <span class="float-left">Float left</span>
  <span class="float-right">Float right</span>
</div>
```

Wrapping everything in **clearfix** div is the key.

Comment: You have 2 inline items, so they need to be in a block element for them to be floated in relation to their siblings.

Comment: @RobertWent Is a `div` not block-level?

Answer (score 4):

I was able to do this with the following classes in my project

```
d-flex justify-content-end

<div class="col-lg-6 d-flex justify-content-end">
```

Answer (score 0):

bootstrap-4 add class float-left or right for floating

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Unfortunately this post does not seem to provide a [quality answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to the question. Please either edit your answer and try provide more details.

Answer (score 0):

Order in bootstrap 5 (2021) has been replaced with order-X

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
         Child 1
    </div>
    <div class="col">
         Child 2
    </div>
    <div class="col">
         Child 3
    </div>
</div>
```

Natural vs. Visual Order
Notice that the natural order of the columns is:

|---1---|---2---|---3---|

Using the flex ordering CSS classes we can change the visual order of the columns...

```
    <div class="row">
          <div class="col order-2"> Child 1 </div>
          <div class="col order-1"> Child 2 </div>
          <div class="col order-3"> Child 3 </div>
    </div>
<!-- Or the belo style if you are using responsive utility
<div class="row">
    <div class="col border order-lg-3"> Child Responsive 1 </div>
    <div class="col border order-lg-2"> Child Responsive 2 </div>
    <div class="col border order-lg-1"> Child Responsive 3 </div>
</div>
```

|---2---|---1---|---3---|

Answer (score 0):

I'm no Bootstrap expert so there may be a better way to do this, but after trying most of the answers here and failing to get any of those solutions to work in my case, I did the following:

```
<div class="row">
<p class="small-text col-lg-4 text-lg-start text-center">© 2021 MyCompany</p>
<p class="small-text col-lg-4 text-lg-center text-center">All trademarks used on this site are the property of their respective owners.</p>
<p class="small-text col-lg-4 text-lg-end text-center">Terms & Conditions | Privacy Policy</p>
</div>
```

For **all viewports smaller than large** this will collapse each one to its own row and centre-align the text.

For **all large viewports and higher** it will distribute each one equally on a single row and align the text accordingly.

Comment: This is because you are trying to align text. the text- classes use the text-align property, not float.

Answer (score -1):

For anyone else and just an addition to Robert, If your nav has flex display value, you can float the element that you need to the right, by adding this to its css

```
{
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

Comment: There are also classes for this `ml-auto` and `mr-auto`