# bootstrap 4 pull-right is not working on navbar

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

1. I am working with bootstrap 4.
2. I didn't get navbar right to the page I don't know what the problem is going on.
3. Is Somebody else can help to fix this issue.

[image]

I have tried to add class pull-right to navbar-collapse div but its don't work. So I have also tried to add float right property and set to !important but its also not get helpful.

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse pull-right" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">HOME</a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">FAQS & HELPS</a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">CONTACT</a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">LOGIN</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I want div content(nav links) to the right of the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you please try **ml-auto** instead of **mr-auto**?

So the ul tag will be like this

```
<ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the following Stack Overflow post

[What happened to the .pull-left and .pull-right classes in Bootstrap 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39655110/what-happened-to-the-pull-left-and-pull-right-classes-in-bootstrap-4/42887127)

Hope this helps you out.